# Just Hide a SSRS Tablix

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report consisting of several text boxes populated from a database.  Some of the text fields are populated using VB code with parameters passed from values created using complex expressions in the Tablix cell.  None of these parameters are displayed on the report

I do not want to show the Tablix on the report but can't seem to accomplish what I thought would be a simple task.  I have set the hidden property on the Tablix to make it hidden, but when I do that and run the report my VB code does not function properly.

I have also tied making sure there are no borders enabled and set font and background colors to white on the Tablix but no luck.

Does anyone have any other suggestion to hide this element

Thanks
Perry

Comment: I would focus on fixing your VB code so that it works when the tablix is hidden.   In what way does it not work properly?

Comment: @Perry, I've experienced the same behaviour while hiding textbox where VB code runs. I ended up thinking that the VB functions doesn't run if the component from it is invoked is hidden at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your input guys.  As @alejandro zuleta pointed out functions called while the Tablix was hidden were not working.  No way to fix it.  So to solve the problem I resized the Tablix to fit in the report without affecting the layout and then formatted everything in the Tablix to white so it does not show on the report.  Not the best fix, but the only one that seemed available at this time.

Thanks
Perry